# Configuring AWS S3 Client in .NET Core

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/configuring-aws-sdk-with-net-core/) guide on configuring the AWS SDK in .NET Core to upload a file to an S3 bucket.

My app.settings.json file contains this:

```
{
  "AWS": {
    "Region": "us-west-1",
    "AccessKey": "access_key",
    "SecretKey": "secret_key"
  }
  ...
}
```

Here is my StartUp class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
        services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
    }
}
```

I believe this means I can just inject a client object into a class which will use the app.settings values. I'm trying to inject the object and make an S3 call like this:

```
public class FileUploader
{
    private readonly IAmazonS3 client;

    public FileUploader(IAmazonS3 client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task Upload()
    {
        var request = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = "bucketName",
            Key = "Test",
            FilePath = "test_file.txt",
            ContentType = "text/plain"
        };

        var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Currently, when I attempt to do this, the app hangs when it tries to inject the S3Client.  Originally, I wasn't trying to inject the S3Client, but rather instantiate it within my FileUploaded class.  I was getting an error then because I wasn't specifying the AccessKey, etc. and I couldn't find a way to set that up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your class name and the function is different, is that a typo.  "assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I should have been including only `Region` and `Profile` in my appsettings.  The profile should be generated using information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/referencing-credentials-using-profiles/).